# Issue with setInterval/clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's a frequently asked question, and I've already read all topics about that.

I've a function which has to simulate a slider :

```
 function fakeSlider(){

        if(!$('.myClass li').last().hasClass('active')){
            $('.myClass li.active').next().trigger('click');
        }else{
            $('.myClass li').first().trigger('click');
        }
    }
```

I called that function on document ready with :

```
var timer = setInterval(fakeSlider, 5000);
```

But next, I want to reset the timer if I click on a $('.myClass li') !
I tried :

```
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        var timer = setInterval(fakeSlider, 5000);
```

It doesn't work (the slider still works, but the timer doesn't reset) and after 10sec, the browser crash.

Comment: Share your example with html markup on jsfiddle please.

Comment: make sure that `timer` is in the same scope for all `setInterval` / `clearInterval` calls, you might not need to write the keyword `var` in the second place `var timer = setInterval(fakeSlider, 5000);`

Comment: Save the return value of `setInterval()` as a `data-*` attribute on the slider. On click you can than use this attribute to clear the interval. No need for a "global" `var` :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that you rewrite timer variable

try

```
window.clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(fakeSlider, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `timer` variables.

One is local to your `ready` function. The other is local to your `click` function.

When you try to clear the first interval, you are using the second `timer` variable, which is `undefined`.

You need to declare (with `var`) the variable in a scope that both functions can access and **not** redeclare it inside `ready` and `click`. Assuming `click` is inside `ready` you can just remove `var` from the second line of the last code block in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, the problem is solved.

Indeed I rewrote **timer** variable two times.

I removed "var" on click function:

```
timer = setInterval(function() {fakeSlider();}, 5000);
```

It works :)

Answer (score -2):

Change your code :

```
var timer = setInterval(fakeSlider, 5000);
```

into:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {fakeSlider();}, 5000);
```

Comment: The anonymous function expression serves no purpose there except to bloat the code and make it harder to read.

Comment: I got this problem when I used setInterval at the first time and this is the way I fix this. Please follow [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) on w3school.

Comment: W3Schools (who are happily now just rubbish instead of the festering pile of awfulness they were a few years ago) use an anonymous function expression in that example because they are passing arguments to the function they call. It won't solve this problem. What's more, their second example doesn't use an anonymous function expression!